# .htaccess conversion of directories (and sub-directories) to query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm sure this has been asked here before, but I can't find the answer. It's really quite simple, I'm sure. I want to take a url like

```
example.com/article/3xamp1e/Some-sort-of-title
```

and convert it to

```
example.com/article?handle=3xamp1e
```

through an htaccess rewriteCond in apache.

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article/([^/]+)/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article?handle=%1 [NC,L,R]
```